# I want to replace the input value using ajax in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to get the student award date and replace the value in the existing input but I write some jquery it is not working place help to fix this issue. I attached my code down.

**Controller**

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
    if($request->studentId!='') {
        $html = "";
        $StudentCDate = Student::where('id', $request->student_id)
                                ->first();

        $data = $StudentCDate->stud_completion_date;
        $html .= $data;
        //$html .=".$StudentCDate->stud_completion_date.";
    }
    return response()->json(['html' => $html]);
}
```

**Jquery Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Department Change
        $('#student_id').change(function(){
            // Department id
            var id = $(this).val();
            //alert(id);
            // Empty the dropdown
            //$('#date').find('input').not(':first').remove();
            // AJAX request
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('StudentCertificateCount/show') }}?studentId=" + id,
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    alert(response.html);
                    //$('#date').val(response.html);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**My Input**

```
<div class="mt-3">
  <label class="flex flex-col sm:flex-row"> Awarded Date </label>
  <input type="text" id="date" name="awarded_date" class="input w-full border mt-2" 
  placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
</div>
```

Comment: what does `alert(response.html);` this gives ?

Comment: It's giving empty. if I put $html .='123'; it will giving the alert.

Comment: So, your query doesn't fetch any datas ? Did you check if the id is pass or not ?

Comment: I try with <option> it is coming

Comment: I think date format issue. date is coming from database (2021-05-07)

Comment: so you are getting date inside success function or not ?